# Why is my SQL CLR stored proc call claiming I am not providing a parameter I am?

Tags: c#, sqlclr

In a CLR procedure I have the following method:

```
private static void EndOwnershipForTeam(long assetId, int teamId)
{
    const string storedProcedureName = @"up_RemoveAssetOwnershipFromTeam";

    using (var connection = new SqlConnection("context connection=true"))
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(storedProcedureName, connection))
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("assetId", assetId);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("teamId", teamId);

        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

When I run this method is called I am getting the following error:

> Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Procedure cp_RemoveAsset, Line 0
>
> A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "cp_RemoveAsset":
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Procedure or function 'up_RemoveAssetOwnershipFromTeam' expects parameter '@assetId', which was not supplied.
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQuerySmi(Boolean sendToPipe)
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult result, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe)
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
>
> at StoredProcedures.EndOwnershipForTeam(Int64 assetId, Int32 teamId)
>
> at StoredProcedures.cp_RemoveAsset(SqlInt32 userId, SqlString xaid)

Since my code is supplying the parameters (verified by displaying output via `SqlContext.Pipe.Send()` calls) why is it claiming that I"m not supplying a parameter I actually am?

Comment: Does your proc call any other procedures?  If so, I would check that you're supplying the params to those correctly.

Comment: Specify command type: `command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like as written, your code is instructing SQL Server to just try executing this:

```
up_RemoveAssetOwnershipFromTeam
```

In other words, just the procedure with no parameters supplied.

To wire up the parameters you need to either specify CommandType.StoredProcedure, or wire up the command parameters explicitly:

```
// option 1
private static void EndOwnershipForTeam(long assetId, int teamId)
{
    const string storedProcedureName = @"up_RemoveAssetOwnershipFromTeam";

    using (var connection = new SqlConnection("context connection=true"))
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(storedProcedureName, connection))
    {
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("assetId", assetId);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("teamId", teamId);

        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}

// option 2
private static void EndOwnershipForTeam(long assetId, int teamId)
{
    const string sql = @"exec up_RemoveAssetOwnershipFromTeam @assetId, @teamId";

    using (var connection = new SqlConnection("context connection=true"))
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@assetId", assetId);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@teamId", teamId);

        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep that was the issue.  I had forgotten to set the Command Type to stored procedure!

Comment: good catch. Though the parameters supplied would be used if the command text formed a *parameterized query* and matched on of the query parameters.

Answer (score 3):

You left out the `@` symbols in your lines

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("assetId", assetId);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("teamId", teamId);
```

They should be

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@assetId", assetId);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@teamId", teamId);
```

Comment: The @ is not required

Comment: @Siyual In some cases it is required, although I'm not sure if this is one of them.

Comment: Some methods may be permissive, but the MSDN documentation for `SqlParameter.ParameterName` indicates that the @ is required, so the safest bet is to always use it.

Comment: I'd think in this case it is required.  Were assetId a reference type instead of a `long` that could cause the same error if it were `null`, but that is not the case here.

Comment: In stored proc calls the @ is not required.

Comment: @KallDrexx They are if you don't set the command type to be a stored procedure. Best practice is to always include the `@`

Comment: I'm pretty sure if you specify it as a stored procedure and include the @ it doesn't work.  I remember having issues like that before.  Too bad it's so confusing when/if you need them :-/

Answer (score 0):

1. You've omitted the '@' prefix.
2. What is the default collation configured for your sql server and/or database? If it is case-sensitive, you'll need to match case exactly.